# How to include a variable in results from SQL PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that contains cells with variable and I want to echo them in PHP with a current variable.

Example:

```
$source = "TEST",

$sql="SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0){
        $data = $row['data'];
}

echo $data;
```

echo $data display

```
www.domain.com?$source
```

but, as final results, I have to get

```
www.domain.com?TEST
```

How to do that?

*Info from MySQL can't be updated/edited

Comment: try putting them in curly braces - like this: `echo "{$data}";`

Comment: Will the variable name be always `$source` inside the $data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable name (substring) inside the `$data` string will always going to be `'$source'`, then you can use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

**Very important:** Use single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`) to represent `'$source'` as a literal string. Do read: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Try the following:

```
$source = "TEST",

$sql="SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0){
        $data = $row['data'];
}

echo str_replace('$source', $source, $data);
```

Comment: echo str_replace('$source',$source,$data);

Comment: @AllCapone1912 happy to help :-) I just added one more explanation about usage of quotes in php. Do go through it.

Comment: Why downvote ? Please explain. Will be happy to correct mistakes (if any)